# script installation that is for both ubuntu 18 and 20 ask for kconfig-frontends package, but it is only for ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

A commercial script I have to setup a development environment in both Ubuntu 18 and 20 asks for `kconfig-frontends` package and this error pops up when executed from Ubuntu 18:

```
E: Unable to locate package kconfig-frontends
```

I have checked [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kconfig-frontends) but it seems the package only appears after focal (20.04LTS). Does that mean that the script is wrongly configured or maybe is there other way to download it for my Ubuntu 18.04?

I'm no expert in package managing, so maybe there is an easy fix.
Of course, I can delete the line of the script that asks for that package, but I want to do it only if there is no other option.

Comment: Have you tried asking the script’s provider?

Comment: I haven't, but if there isn't a proper way to fix it, I will. Just wanted to be sure beforehand.